# Automatically save my SQL Server query results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that compiles some data based on a supplied Id number. I want to run it once for a long list of Ids that I have, and save the result set to a CSV. I know I can do it manually, but I'm looking for an automated way.

I already tried running my query without specifying the Id in the where clause. This ended up giving my a file a little smaller than 1Gb which is too big for needs.

Here is the basic idea of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
Declare @num int
set @num = 0
While @num < 100
Begin

    --I'm trying to figure out a way to store the 
    --result set generateed by this procedure is saved to 'DataExtract' + @num + '.csv'
    Exec LongRunningProcedure @num
    Set @num = @num + 1
End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have sufficient permissions you could use powershell to accomplish this. I can't really be sure that this will run exactly right for you because I don't know what your output looks like, but hopefully this will get you where you're going.

```
$SQLAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SQLCommand = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

[STRING]$SQLServer = 'YourServer';
[STRING]$SQLDatabase = 'YourDatabase';
[STRING]$SQLConnectString = "Data Source=$SQLServer; Initial Catalog=$SQLDatabase;    Integrated Security=True";
$SQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($SQLConnectString)

$extractFile = "C:\test.csv"

for($x = 0; $x -le 100; $x++) {

    $file = "$($extractFile.Split('.')[0])$($x).csv"
    $SQLQuery = "Exec LongRunningProcedure @num = $x"
    $SQLConnection.Open()

    $SQLCommand.CommandText = $SQLQuery
    $SQLCommand.Connection = $SQLConnection

    $SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLCommand
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) | Out-Null

    $SQLConnection.Close() 

    $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $file
}
```

Comment: An additional resource is http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/03/powershell-export-query-to-csv.html